# How to use pyhook to capture Chinese input?

Tags: pyhook

According to http://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/, I successfully capture pure keyboard input by pyhook. However, I face another issue is that I want to capture user Chinese input through [Google Pinyin Input](http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ime/pinyin/) or other similar Input software. Any advice?

Comment: So what problems are you encoutering?

Comment: The problem is that PyHook only could capture keyboard input, rather than output by Chinese PinYin Input.